# How do you determine the DC of a Strength Save?

Tags: dnd-5e, saving-throw, fighter

As example I'm using *Pushing Attack* from the *Battle Master* Martial archetypes of the Fighter. How do you determine the Strength Save DC that the enemy has to roll against?

Since normally it would be a deal of the attacker and defender roll a competing roll but here it just says they roll against... what?

Am I missing something? I appreciate any help anyone can give!

Answer (score 15):

The DC for an enemy's saving throw depends on the class feature you have that is causing them to make a saving throw. Generally the DC follows a formula of 8 + your proficiency + an ability modifier.

For any Battlemaster Fighter abilities, there is [a section that describes the saving throw](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/fighter#BattleMaster) (PHB page 73):

> **Saving Throws**. Some of your maneuvers require your target to make a saving throw to resist the maneuver’s effects. The saving throw DC is calculated as follows:
>
> **Maneuver save DC** = 8 + your proficiency bonus + your Strength or Dexterity modifier (your choice)

Comment: Thank you so much! we're using Fantasy ground so my resources are limited eg: I don't have an actual book to read through and hopefully find it just little snippets that people thought were important basicalyl a skeleton of a PHB

Comment: @dia The full text is in Fantasy Grounds, if you bought the resources. You're probably not looking in the right place.

Answer (score 6):

## Determined by your [Maneuver Save DC](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/fighter#BattleMaster)

> 8 + your proficiency bonus + your Strength or Dexterity modifier (your choice)

(PHB, pp73)